# ffmpeg issue with output from video stream

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, video-streaming, rtsp

I have two video streams from which I'd like to take one frame of each, both of them are RTSP. I'm using the same FFMPEG instruction for both of them but changing the URL of the stream, the first one works but the second one throws the error:

> method SETUP failed: 455 Method Not Valid In This State

Can anyone tell me what could be the reason for this error and how to solve it?

**WORKING**

```
ffmpeg -ss 1 -i rtsp://streamreader:trudat55@69.84.126.216:88/videoMain -an -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -aspect 16:9 -q:v 2 -y test.jpg

ffmpeg version 2.8.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-avresample --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-postproc --enable-version3 --enable-shared --enable-pic --extra-ldexeflags=-pie
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[rtsp @ 0x55a60a0a7420] UDP timeout, retrying with TCP
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://streamreader:password@69.84.126.216:88/videoMain':
  Metadata:
    title           : IP Camera Video
    comment         : videoMain
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.200044, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Baseline), yuv420p, 640x480, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_mulaw, 8000 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 64 kb/s
[swscaler @ 0x55a60a102460] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
Output #0, image2, to 'test.jpg':
  Metadata:
    title           : IP Camera Video
    comment         : videoMain
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc), 640x480 [SAR 4:3 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 50 fps, 50 tbn, 50 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 mjpeg
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mjpeg (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    1 fps=0.5 q=2.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.02 bitrate=N/A dup=1 drop=1    
video:66kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

**NOT WORKING**

```
ffmpeg -ss 1 -i rtsp://camaras.corredorautomotriz.cl:554/live.sdp -an -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -aspect 16:9 -q:v 2 -y test.jpg

ffmpeg version 2.8.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-avresample --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-postproc --enable-version3 --enable-shared --enable-pic --extra-ldexeflags=-pie
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[rtsp @ 0x55b98f2de420] UDP timeout, retrying with TCP
[rtsp @ 0x55b98f2de420] method SETUP failed: 455 Method Not Valid In This State
[rtsp @ 0x55b98f2de420] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: mjpeg, none(bt470bg/unknown/unknown)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://camaras.corredorautomotriz.cl:554/live.sdp':
  Metadata:
    title           : RTSP server
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, none(bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Data: none
Output #0, image2, to 'test.jpg':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

Comment: I checked the second stream with *FFmpeg* built from current sources and everything works fine.

Comment: Hello @EdgarRokyan , What do you mean when you say you checked with the built from current sources? You mean when all the ffmpeg libs are enabled? Did it work for you that way? Thanks

Comment: Ohm, sorry, sometimes it's difficult for me to make a correct phrase in English)) I have *FFmpeg* that was built from fresh *github* sources a few months ago. It works fine with your second command.

Comment: Also I built it without any configuration changes, so I have only libs that're enabled by default.

Comment: ok, I get it. @EdgarRokyan Could you show me the libs that you have enabled, please? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not really good at *FFmpeg*. Please, specify commands I need to check...

Comment: Just type `ffmpeg` on your command line and show me the output. Thanks @EdgarRokyan

Comment: Ok, I see. It's not interesting, just: http://pastebin.com/iftsEFWT

Comment: That's interesting. You don't have any configuration parameter enabled for ffmpeg. What if you do `ffmpeg --buildconf`? Any difference? @EdgarRokyan

Comment: Output is still the same... I can only advise you to build *FFmpeg* from repo and check it locally or try some other versions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see in your output, `ffmpeg` failed to determine input stream type in the second case (rtsp://camaras.corredorautomotriz.cl:554/live.sdp).

I checked it, and it got me *mpeg4*:

> Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://camaras.corredorautomotriz.cl:554/live.sdp':
>
> Metadata:
>
> title           : RTSP server
>
> Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
>
> Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile), yuv420p, 720x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 3:2], 30 tbr, 30k tbn

Thus possibly you compiled **ffmpeg** without *mpeg4* decoder (or with broken decoder).

Answer (score 2):

I found that if I specify that the protocol is TCP with the instruction `-rtsp_transport tcp` then i don't get an error:

ffmpeg -ss 5 -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://camaras.corredorautomotriz.cl:554/live.sdp  -s 640x480  -aspect 16:9  -b:v 800k -r 24  video.flv

But I would still like to know the reason and solution of the problem I got before, because I am not sure I can use this parameter. Anyone knows?

Thanks